# Handling multiple Observables and functions

Tags: angular, function, observable

On selection of particular collection from list, I have to fetch headers using http call. Some times observable respond quickly and data gets populated as expected but many times when observable takes time. If we wait for observable to respond, it works as expected but when selection of collection switched quicky, because first observable has not yet responded and new one is fired, createHeader() gets messedup completely.

I have read many articles and got to know that debounceTime helps here to hold observable. I have tried but didn't work.

```
  selectCollection(){
    console.log('Selected Collection :', this.selectedCollection)
    this.buildURL();
    console.log('URL :', this.url1)
    this.columnDefs = [];
    this.getHeader()
  }

  buildURL(){
    this.url1 = this.prefixURL + JSON.stringify(this.selectedCollection)
  }

  getHeader(){
    let recordsObs$ = this.httpService.ajaxCall('GET', this.url1, this.reqData)
    recordsObs$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Records :',data)
      this.records = data
      this.createHeader(this.records[0])
    })
  }

  createHeader(records){
    this.columnDefs.push(this._header)
    console.log('create Header',records)
    records.fields.forEach(field => {
      console.log(field)
      var header = new Header();
      header.headerName = field.fieldLabel
      header.field = field.fieldName
      header.width = 150
      this.columnDefs.push(header)
    })
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs)
  }
```

Expected result is: If I quickly switch the items from the list, all previous observable should be discarded and only the latest data should get utilised for createHeader().

Comment: I suggest you read up on state management in Angular apps. In particular those topics: BehaviorSubject, ngrx, ngxs, angular-redux, mobx. Essentially you pre-load the data into the client and create selectors or filter/transformation functions with the pre-loaded data. If you rely on too many http calls it will eventually lead to such errors as you're experiencing. mobx is easiest to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be to save the reference to subscription and cancel it if another request is made:

```js
...
recordSubscription: Subscription;

getHeader(){
    if (this.recordSubscription) {
        this.recordSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.recordSubscription = null;
    }
    let recordsObs$ = this.httpService.ajaxCall('GET', this.url1, this.reqData)
    this.recordSubscription = recordsObs$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Records :',data)
      this.records = data
      this.createHeader(this.records[0])
    })
  }

...
```

On the other hand, if you encounter this situation often, you might want to consider using some state management lib like the ones altu mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681433/handling-multiple-observables-and-functions#comment103663215_58681433).